# Why is import package outside module visible from other files/modules?

Tags: system-verilog

- file A

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps
import mypkg::*;
module test_A (
...
);
```

- file B:

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps
module test_B (
...
);
```

- Why are typedef of `mypkg` visible in file B?
  Isn't it supposed to be per compilation unit (=file here)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section *3.12.1 Compilation units* of the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) gives tools the choice of handling each file as a separate compilation unit like in C/C++, or every file being compiled on the command line as one compilation unit like in Verilog. All tools treat each file as a separate compilation unit if they are compiled with separate command lines.

Unfortunately there is no standard default choice; you need to read your tool's User Manual.

I know that Modelsim/Questa treats each SystemVerilog file as a separate compilation unit by default.

Comment: alright.. Vivado seems to treat them as global and it isn't easy to find out which file declared an import in the file outside a module declaration. Thanks!

Comment: synopsys for sure does not treat files as separate compilation units and all macro definitions,  declarations in global scope, including results of import are sticky and are visible in the files which follow on the command line.

Comment: I'll avoid declaring such import in compilation unit global scope then.